# Story about a woman who is abducted by a green sphere

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The woman is abducted by a green sphere, but is soon made an agent of the interstellar organization that the sphere is a part of. She meets a lot of different aliens and soon becomes friends with the sphere, who is sort-of her handler(?).

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time.  Please remove one of your questions.

Also, can you add details please.  When did you read this? How old? Do you recall any artwork?

Comment: Maybe this could be made on-topic if were rephrased as a request for identifying the collection rather than the two separate stories?

Comment: Sorry. I will remove the second question. I would have read the first story about 5-10 years ago, but I think that it's much older: 80's or 90's. There was no artwork

Comment: If there is widespread agreement regarding adding in the second story due to it maybe being part of a collection then I will do so.

Comment: green sphere made me think of Heavy Metal, but there wasn't anything friendly about it, the sphere was concentrated evil

Comment: Yeah, I think the woman thought the sphere was scary at first, but after a while (basically a time skip) she considered it to be a familiar friend.